# Panel AutoScroll position setting

Tags: c#, .net

How to set the AutoScrollPosition to the bottom most position?

I tried

```
panel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, panel.Height);
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the panel's `VerticalScroll.Maximum`-property:

```
panel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(
    Math.Abs(panel.AutoScrollPosition.X), 
    panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum);
```